# how to set common code once in YII

Tags: php, yii

i wanted to know in which file we can set common code, for example i wanted to set timezone to UTC, instead of putting same code in all controllers file is there any way to put the code once and it will be reflect in all files.

Comment: To set timezone just add `timeZone='your_time_zone'` in application config. See http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#timeZone-detail

Answer (score 1):

You may create your file in ''components'' folder. You can see this folder in "protected" folder.

Or you can write your code in controller.php

File path: webroot/protected/components/Controller.php

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to add the codes in  bootstrap.php file

If you need to set the server time you can check here.It is a simple method

[Change time zone](http://www.mochasupport.com/kayako/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=522)

Answer (score 0):

Use application params, ie:

```
// config part
return array(
// ...
    'params' => array(
         'myParam' => 123
     )
// ...
);

// Then in app use
Yii::app()->params['myParam'] // Will return 123
```

You can also create your own *params holder* as component, ie:

```
// config part
    'components' => array(
          'myConfigs' => array(
                'class' => 'ext.MyConfigs'
                'myParam1' => 123,
                'myParam2' => 'blah'
           )
     )

// Component in extensions
class MyConfigs extends CComponent
{
    public $myParam1;
    public $myParam2 = 'defaultValue';
}

// Then in app use it:
Yii::app()->myConfigs->myParam1 // will return 123
```